# trigonometric inequality: $\frac{1}{\tan (\frac{\pi}{2}t)}(s-t)\leq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

I am looking for all the real number $t\in [-1,1]$ verifying the following inequality:
$$\frac{1}{\tan (\frac{\pi}{2}t)}(s-t)\leq 0,$$
for all $s\in [-1,1]$.

So far I have found $t=1$, I wanna know if $t=1$ is the only real number between $-1$ and $1$verifying the inequality.

Comment: The LHS is not even *defined* for $t=1$. The question is not entirely clear: are you looking 1/ for values of $t$ such that the inequality is true for any $s$? or 2/ given a fixed $s$, for values of $t$ such that the inequality is true?

Answer (score 0):

The expression is well defined for $t\in (-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ and we have that:

- for $0<t<1 \implies \tan (\frac{\pi}{2}t)>0$ then

$$\frac{1}{\tan (\frac{\pi}{2}t)}(s-t)\leq 0 \iff s-t\leq 0 \iff -1\le s\le t$$

- for $-1<t<0 \implies \tan (\frac{\pi}{2}t)<0$ then

$$\frac{1}{\tan (\frac{\pi}{2}t)}(s-t)\leq 0 \iff s-t\geq 0 \iff t\le s\le 1$$

Now $\forall t_+\in (0,1)$ we can take $s\in (t_+,1)$ such that

$$\frac{1}{\tan (\frac{\pi}{2}t)}(s-t)> 0$$

and $\forall t_-\in (-1,0)$ we can take $s\in (-1,t_-)$ such that

$$\frac{1}{\tan (\frac{\pi}{2}t)}(s-t)> 0$$

therefore such $t$ doesn't exist.

Comment: The question is not finding $s$, $s$ is in fact arbitrary in $[-1,1]$, and we need to find which $t$ satisfies the inequality.

Comment: @BrianTag Ah ok! I revise that. Thanks

Comment: @BrianTag I've edited the answer. Let me know if all is clear. Bye